# jquery - multiple forms in a page - check for empty field in a different form from the one submitted

Tags: jquery, forms, http-post

I have two different forms, while submitting form with `#orchestrationForm`, I would want to see if the `filePaths` text box in form with `#blah` is empty. How to do this in jquery?

My HTML and jquery are as follows:

```html
<form id="blah"></form>
<form method="POST" action="/api/wand" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="orchestrationForm">
  <section id="data-files">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filePaths" form="blah" />
  </section>
</form>
```

```js
$("#orchestrationForm").on("submit", function() {
  var noFiles = false;
  $("[name='filePaths']", this).each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      noFiles = true;
    }
  });
  if (noFiles) {
    alert("Upload atleast one file");
  }
  return false;
});
```

while submitting my orchestration form i am searching by name attribute for `filePaths`, if they are empty, am showing an alert box. The problem is, even when the `filePaths` text box is not empty, `noFiles` evaluates to true and the alert box gets shown. What is wrong with my jquery?

Comment: `noFiles` is only retaining the value of the last file input field checked. You overwrite it on every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're doing, but I suspect you're building  form to upload multiple files. I created a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/p75tzcvj/

**HTML**

```
<form id="blah">
  <h2>
  Form 1
  </h2>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="/api/wand" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="orchestrationForm">
  <h2>
  Form 2
  </h2>
  <section id="data-files">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="filePaths" form="blah" />
  </section>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#orchestrationForm").on("submit", function() {
    var noFiles = false;
    $("input[name='filePaths']", this).each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        noFiles = true;
      }
    });
    if (noFiles) {
      alert("Upload atleast one file");
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

If the field is empty, the alert is displayed. `!$(this).val()` will equate to true in both cases. Use `$(this).val() === ""` so that when it is not empty, it will return false. In my example, an empty field provides the alert, an non-empty field will not provide the alert, but the form fails due to the `return false`.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. Thank you. Why is $(this).val() === "" not same as !$(this).val() ? I do understand === is meant for strict comparison.

Comment: I have to research it, but, `!$(this).val()` returns `true` regardless of the content in the target. comparing the value to "" with either `==` or `===` is going to give you a `true` or `false` result each time.

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/n53qg34t/ So maybe it's something about how the `.each()` is handling `$(this)`.